# Can I Map Enum Keys to Enum Values?

Tags: java, enum-map

I have 2 enums (Modules, UniqueChars)

Modules has all the Keys

UniqueChars has all the values.

How can I map these using HashMap or EnumMap?

Firstly, Is it possible to read the keys & values from 2 seperate enums??

```
public enum modules {
    MODULE("MTREE, VTL_POOL, VTL_ACCESS, SNAPSHOT, NFS_EXPORT, CIFS_SHARE, REPORTS, LOCAL_USERS ");

    private String validModules;

    private modules(String validModules) {
        this.validModules= validModules;
    }
}

public enum UniqueChars {
    LOWER_CASE_LETTERS("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 
    UPPER_CASE_LETTERS("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 
    NUMBERS("0123456789"), 
    PUNCTUATION(".-_"), 
    MTREE("*/:<>?\\|"), 
    VTL_POOL("*'?:/\\,"), 
    VTL_ACCESS("*'?:/\\,"),
    SNAPSHOT("`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\\:\";'<>?,.'"),
    NFS_EXPORT("_-"),
    CIFS_SHARE("\\/:*?\"<>|+[];,="),
    REPORTS("`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\\:\";'<>?,.'"),
    LOCAL_USERS("._-");

    private String validChars;

    private UniqueChars(String validChars) {
        this.validChars = validChars;
    }


    public String getValidChars() {
        return validChars;
    }

    public static String getValidCharStrings(UniqueChars... uniqueChars) {
        StringBuilder validCharsSB = new StringBuilder();
        for (UniqueChars chars : uniqueChars) {
            validCharsSB.append(chars.getValidChars());
        }
        return validCharsSB.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "modules" enum (which should be renamed "Module") is broken as it has only one member and no public methods. What use is it? Next, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Please explain in a bit more detail your ultimate goal and what the code you've posted is supposed to do and isn't.

Comment: I want to do map.put(Module.Mtree, UniqueChars.getValidCharStrings(UniqueChars.MTree)) ... in the same way I want to map all the modules in Module enum to their corresponding values in UniqueChars enum.  Currently I have only one enum UniqueChars, which I am mapping using a switch case. Insted of switch case I want to use 2 enums and loop the map.put statement.

Answer (score 2):

yes:

```
import java.util.*;
enum color {
    r,g,b
}
enum letter {
    a,b,c
}
public class So16659089 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(map);
        System.out.println(map2);
    }
    static Map<color,letter> map=new EnumMap<color,letter>(color.class);
    static { // one way
        map.put(color.r,letter.a);
        map.put(color.g,letter.b);
        map.put(color.b,letter.c);
    }
    static Map<color,letter> map2=new EnumMap<color,letter>(color.class);
    static letter[] letters=new letter[]{letter.a,letter.b,letter.c};
    static { // another way
        for(int i=0;i<color.values().length;i++)
            map2.put(color.values()[i],letters[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I have 10 enum constants in color & letter, do I neer to write 10 map.put statements or can I loop them. If I can loop them, how to do that? Thanks

Comment: @VarunMukka You can iterate over the values of an enumeration calling (for instance) `modules.values()`. This returns an array with all `modules` declared values.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the above posted code in an API. I want to replace the switch block by HashMap or EnumMap. Don't want to use 'n' put Statements for 'n' cases.

public String getUniqueString(int charCount, boolean validSpecialChar,
            UniqueChars module, boolean invalidSpecialChar, String... specialChars) {

```
    final int STRING_LENGTH = this.getRandomNumber(charCount);
    String finalString = "";
    String validCharStrings = "";

    if(!validSpecialChar){
        validCharStrings = UniqueChars.getValidCharStrings(
                UniqueChars.LOWER_CASE_LETTERS,
                UniqueChars.UPPER_CASE_LETTERS, UniqueChars.NUMBERS);
    } else {
        UniqueChars moduleName = null;
        switch (module) {
        case MTREE:
            moduleName = UniqueChars.MTREE;
            break;
        case VTL_POOL:
            moduleName = UniqueChars.VTL_POOL;
            break;
        case VTL_ACCESS:
            moduleName = UniqueChars.VTL_ACCESS;
            break;
        case SNAPSHOT:
            moduleName = UniqueChars.SNAPSHOT;
            break;
        case NFS_EXPORT:
            moduleName = UniqueChars.NFS_EXPORT;
            break;
        case CIFS_SHARE:
            moduleName = UniqueChars.CIFS_SHARE;
            break;
        case REPORTS:
            moduleName = UniqueChars.REPORTS;
            break;
        case LOCAL_USERS:
            moduleName = UniqueChars.LOCAL_USERS;
            break;
        }

        // If specialChar is true, special characters are included for the
        // specified module
        validCharStrings = UniqueChars.getValidCharStrings(
                UniqueChars.LOWER_CASE_LETTERS,
                UniqueChars.UPPER_CASE_LETTERS, UniqueChars.NUMBERS,
                moduleName);
    }
```

Comment: You should update your question with this extra information, instead of adding it as an answer. You'll easily spot an *edit* button below your question.